# wpf button background change

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the button color on click event.

**This is my code:**

```
 <Button Content="Start"
 Command="{Binding DataContext.StartCounterCommand, ElementName=dgTemplate1}"
 CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dgTemplate1}" />
```

Comment: If you can suggest to change the content of the button.. that will be more helpful for me

Comment: ..and what is "this" issue?

Comment: Did you try binding the backgroundcolor to another property in your viewmodel? And change that property in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Use a style trigger on the pressed state, something like:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I dug up a good sample that is close [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795896/set-button-content-on-button-click-trigger-in-xaml)

If you are using MVVM them binding to a view model is also a good option as per @schlonzo